# Why does the artist image sometime not appear on the lock screen?

Tags: zune, personalization

Sometimes there's no artist image on the lock screen while I'm playing music. I get a default red screen instead. How can I add an artist image?

**EDIT:** Slight misunderstanding. I am in a region where the artists can be shown on the lock screen. Most of the time the artist is shown, but in some cases there's only the default image. For these artists with missing images how can I add one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, so for the edit: This is dependent on your few things:

- active/accessible internet connection
- zune music pass must offer music from this artist in order to have some pictures of it/him/her
- artist must be accessible for your country (yes again the same problem) - not all artist are accessible in all countries... :(

But there may be some other things that affect artist background accessibility...

---

Unfortunately, this feature depends on the country where you live in. It depends on availability of music marketplace, which is not available in all countries. If you are one of those unhappy users, you must get used to that orange-purple screen which is rendered instead of artist image.

But if you are lucky and you have access to the music marketplace and you still don't see artist image instead of wallpaper when playing music, go to the **settings** -> **lock+wallpaper** and switch on the **show artist when playing music** checkbox.

If you want to check music marketplace (called Zune Pass, if I am not mistaken) availability for your country, go to the zune.net page and choose to change locale ([use this link](http://www.zune.net/cs-CZ/ChangeLocale.htm)). If you compare US version of the zune.net page and yours, you may see there's something missing.

---

You can see the difference between US and CZ version of the page on images below:

The US version offers Zune Music Pass:
[image: Full Zune page (US)]

---

The CZ version offers only the software:
[image: Zune for CZ]

---

I also found [this ugly chart](http://wmpoweruser.com/zune-regional-availability-chart-released/), where the data seems to be also right.

Comment: This explains why mine doesn't work at all. I was hoping it was a bug. For completeness, do you have a source link for this (hopefully with a country list)?

Comment: I edited the answer, added some info. Look at it if it gives the info you want.

Comment: I think I can confirm what @jumbo said. I have my phone locked to pt-BR and I can't see album in lock screen and in music+video hub. My mate has locked to en-US and all works great.

Comment: I edited my question to better reflect my intent.

Comment: @Andrew edited again, check it :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to embed artwork by dragging an image file onto WMP. This artwork should be shown when by WP7 when playing music.